# Cakephp HABTM many to many relation

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

Hello I'm having trouble setting up a simple HABTM in cakephp.

Please tell me what is wrong? I followed the documentation closely.

My controller (it's a REST service)

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $this->set(array(
            'users' => $this->User->find('all'),
            '_serialize' => array('users')
        ));
    }
}
```

My User.php model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Sport' => array(
            'className' => 'Sport',
            'joinTable' => 'sports_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'sport_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

My Sport.php Model

```
class Sport extends AppModel{

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'sports_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'sport_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

And this is how my DB looks like:

The users table:

[image]

The sports table:

[image]

Finally the sports_users table:

[image]

Lastly this is the error I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\SportsAround\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php on line 3627
```

Full image:

[image]

So where did I got it wrong? Thank you

Comment: Any one? I haven't solved it

Comment: not completely clear, the error you are getting is when you execute `$this->User->find('all')`, right? set recursive to -1 and try again, if it's the same error, the problem is not the habtm, but the user model alone (in that case, post all user model to see what's up)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The code uploaded is my complete code. How do I set recursive to -1? Yes the problem comes when I call find('all')

Comment: That is in fact all the code I have in my app. Plus some lines in config files.

Comment: try doing `class User extends AppModel {public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Sport');}` and `class Sport extends AppModel{  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');}`, and before the `$this->set` put this `$users = $this->User->find('all', array('recursive'=>-1)); pr($users);`, to see what you've got

Comment: Ok I'm driving... I will test it in about 20 mins and come back with an answer. Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Ok ok, but *please*, don't text and drive o.o Receiving feedback for a comment isn't *that* urgent.

Comment: Ok that solved it. I still don't know what was wrong before, but declaring the $hasAndBelongsToMany as a simple String array solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Sport' => array(
        'className' => 'Sport',
        'joinTable' => 'sports_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'sport_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'with' => ''
    )
);
```

To

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Sport');
```

And

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'sports_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'sport_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'with' => ''
    )
);
```

To

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
```

But I still don't understand why that solved it.

Comment: If you follow CakePhp naming conventions you don't have to specify any options and just indicate the association as you did here. An incorrect setting that you applied where you didn't need to likely caused a problem.